# A decrease in or a decrease of?

Tags: prepositions

I was in chemistry class when this question struck me, which sentence is more accurate?

> A decrease ***in*** the mass of a reactant.

or

> A decrease ***of*** the mass of a reactant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is inaccurate, and both of the expressions are used, but "decrease **in** the" occurs about five times more frequently, so that is the expression that should be used.
Here is a Google Ngram comparison
[Ngram "decrease in/of the"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=decrease%20in%20the%2Cdecrease%20of%20the&year_start=1920&year_end=2012&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdecrease%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdecrease%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0)

(You may note that both expressions seem to decrease after about 1980, but I think that is a reflection of the date of the corpus (2012) and the fact that these phrases occur in technical materials like textbooks and scientific papers, which may not get included in the corpus as promptly as newspapers, magazines and other sources.)